# Can't mark only spaces

Tags: regular-expressions, whitespace

I want to select by regexp only spaces.

Here text:

```
test-hello how-are again ok
maybe good but-some not good
```

I use regexp

```
[:space:]
```

but it's not work:

[image]

Comment: Please say what command(s) you use. And please clarify whether you want to find all stretches of whitespace, of any kind, or just space characters. `[[:space:]]` matches whitespace characters of all kinds, and those depend on the current syntax table.

Comment: "\s-" this also work

Comment: The regexp you used, `[:space:]` matches the colon, `:`, and any letter in the word "space" (so it is equivalent to, say, `[aceps:]`). To match a space you could use `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose your `:space:` class in `[]`:

```
"[[:space:]]"
```

Comment: "\s-" this also work